# Mock httpcontext.current.request.files

Tags: c#, httpcontext, nunit-2.5.9

I am implementing nUnit Test case for one of my method called, **UploadFile()**, some thing like below

```
 public void UploadFile(string siteId, string sitePageId)
 {
    int fileCount = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count;

    //Rest of code
 }
```

so basically i am reading file using **HttpContext.Current.Request.Files**.
From UI it is working fine but when i am implementing nUnit test case for it, i am not able to mock **HttpContext.Current.Request.Files**. I googled about some of mocking tools but there also i didn't get anything related to mocking of **HttpContext.Current.Request.Files**. Please help me how to mock it or write test case for my method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dependency injection and then inject an instance of HttpContextBase into the class. Supposing you're using MVC:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    HttpContextBase _context;        

    public MyController(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context
    }

    public void UploadFile(string siteId, string sitePageId)
    {
        int fileCount = _context.Request.Files.Count;

        //Rest of code
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate the controller with a mock of HttpContextBase. This is how you would do it with Moq:

```
[Test]
public void File_upload_test()
{
    var contextmock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    // Set up the mock here
    var mycontroller = new MyController(contextmock.Object);
    // test here
}
```

Comment: I am not using MVC :(

Comment: The same concept applies to Web forms. You can also use constructor injection. You just have to look up how to set up your DI container. I did this in MVC just as an example

Comment: To be frank i am not getting how to setup mock , just take a example of any file and will you write code for me