# Testing a Web API method that uses HttpContext.Current.Request.Files?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, httpcontext

I am attempting to write a test for a Web API method that uses `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` and after exhaustive searching and experimentation I cannot figure out how to mock for it.  The method being tested looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    var requestFiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    var file = requestFiles.Get(0);
    //do some other stuff...
}
```

I realize that there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21183816/27457) [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452418/27457), but they do not address this specific situation.

If I attempt to mock the context, I run into issues with the `Http*` object hierarchy.  Say I set up various mock objects (using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)) like this:

```
var mockFiles = new Mock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
mockFiles.Setup(s => s.Count).Returns(1);
var mockFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
mockFile.Setup(s => s.InputStream).Returns(new MemoryStream());
mockFiles.Setup(s => s.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(mockFile.Object);
var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockRequest.Setup(s => s.Files).Returns(mockFiles.Object);
var mockContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockContext.Setup(s => s.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);
```

Attempting to assign it to the current context...

```
HttpContext.Current = mockContext.Object;
```

...results in a compiler error/redline because it `Cannot convert source type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' to target type 'System.Web.HttpContext'`.

I have also tried drilling into various context objects that come with the constructed controller object, but can't find one that a) is the return object of an `HttpContext.Current` call in the controller method body and b) provides access to standard `HttpRequest` properties, like `Files`.

```
var requestMsg = controller.Request;   //returns HttpRequestMessage
var context = controller.ControllerContext;  //returns HttpControllerContext
var requestContext = controller.RequestContext;   //read-only returns HttpRequestContext
```

It is also important to note that **I cannot change the controller that I'm testing at all, so I cannot change the constructor to allow the context to be injected.**

Is there any way to mock `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` for unit testing in Web API?

**Update**
Though I'm not sure this will be accepted by the team, I am experimenting with changing the Post method to use `Request.Content`, as suggested by [Martin Liversage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98607/martin-liversage).  It currently looks something like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    var uploadFileStream = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(@"C:\temp");
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(uploadFileStream);
    //do the stuff to get the file
    return ActionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "it worked!");
}
```

My test looks similar to this:

```
var byteContent = new byte[]{};
var content = new MultipartContent { new ByteArrayContent(byteContent) };
content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext 
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Content = new MultipartContent { new ByteArrayContent(byteContent) }
        }
};
```

Now I'm getting an error on `ReadAsMultipartAsync`:

`System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type 'MultipartFormDataStreamProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Did not find required 'Content-Disposition' header field in MIME multipart body part.`

Comment: As an aside, if you truly can't change your code to remove the direct coupling on the `HttpContext.Current` dependency, there is a long winded way to do [this via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31177399/314291)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Web API has been built to support unit testing by allowing you to mock various context objects. However, by using `HttpContext.Current` you are using "old-style" `System.Web` code that uses the `HttpContext` class which makes it impossible to unit test your code.

To allow your code to be unit testable you have to stop using `HttpContext.Current`. In [Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) you can see how to upload files using Web API. Ironically, this code also uses `HttpContext.Current` to get access to the `MapPath` but in Web API you should use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` that also works outside IIS. Mocking the later is also problematic but for now I am focusing on your question about mocking the request.

Not using `HttpContext.Current` allows you to unit test your controller by assigning the `ControllerContext` property of the controller:

```
var content = new ByteArrayContent( /* bytes in the file */ );
content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext {
  Request = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Content = new MultipartContent { content }
  }
};
var controller = new MyController();
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Please see my update above about content-disposition.

Comment: @AJ: I have updated the code. You have to set the `Content-Disposition` header of the inner content, not on the multi-part content.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - I'm trying to get this to work, and not having much luck - if you have time, any chance you can take a look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073646/httprequestmessage-content-disposition-null-when-unit-testing

Comment: Corrected URL for the Sending HTML Form Data article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

Comment: This does not answer the question!

Comment: This works.  If you actually need to deal with more file information set the content disposition to include the filename: ("Content-Disposition", @"form-data; filename=""filename.jpg""") and make sure you set the content type: content.Headers.Add("Content-Type","image/png")

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is perfect for the OP's question. I wanted to add my solution here, which derives from Martin's, as this is the page I was directed to when simply searching on how to Mock out the Request object for Web API so I can add headers my Controller is looking for. I had a difficult time finding the simple answer:

```
   var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext();
   controllerContext.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
   controllerContext.Request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");

   MyController controller = new MyController(MockRepository);
   controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

And there you are; a very simple way to create controller context with which you can "Mock" out the Request object and supply the correct headers for your Controller method.

Answer (score -1):

I mocked just the posted file. I believe all files can also be mocked this way.

> This was in my controller

```
private HttpPostedFileBase _postedFile;

/// <summary>
/// For mocking HttpPostedFile
/// </summary>
public HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile
{
    get
    {
        if (_postedFile != null) return _postedFile;
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("HttpContext not available");
        }
        return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).Request.Files[0];
    }
    set { _postedFile = value; }
}

[HttpPost]
public MyResponse Upload()
{
    if (!ValidateInput(this.PostedFile))
    {
        return new MyResponse
        {
            Status = "Input validation failed"
        };
    }
}

private bool ValidateInput(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength == 0)
        return false;

    if (file.ContentType != "test")
        return false;

    if (file.ContentLength > (1024 * 2048))
        return false;

    return true
}
```

> This was in my Unit test case

```
public void Test1()
{
    var controller = new Mock<MyContoller>();
    controller.Setup(x => x.Upload).Returns(new CustomResponse());

    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Request.Content = new StreamContent(GetContent());
    controller.PostedFile = GetPostedFile();

    var result = controller.Upload().Result;
}

private HttpPostedFileBase GetPostedFile()
{
    var postedFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        postedFile.Setup(pf => pf.InputStream).Returns(stream);
        postedFile.Setup(pf => pf.ContentLength).Returns(1024);
        postedFile.Setup(pf => pf.ContentType).Returns("bmp");
    }
    return postedFile.Object;
}
```

> Although, I was not able to successfully mock the HTTPContext. But, I
>   was able to mock the file upload.