# Difference between HttpControllerContext.Request and HttpContext.Current.Request

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpcontext, request-headers, asp.net-apicontroller

Im just trying to Unit-Test my custom `ApiController`. In my custom controller i override the `Initialize` method to evaluate the authorization-header.

So my problem is, that i there are 2 request-headers available.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    // Headers 1
    var headersOne = controllerContext.Request.Headers;
    // Headers 2
    var headersTwo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;
}
```

But this it not the problem itself. The problem is, that the headers don't match. So for the productive operating: Where do i have to look for the authorization-header. And where do i have to apply my authorization-header for my test-scenario.

At the moment i apply the authorization-header to the `controllerContext`:

```
var fakeControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/test"),
        Headers =
        {
            { "Authorization", "Fake Authorization-Header"}
        }
    }
};
```

But as i already said. The header is later not available in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers`.
Can you please help me out? Unfortunately i don't exactly understand which context fulfills what purpose.

Comment: Maybe here is the anwer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189028/testing-a-web-api-method-that-uses-httpcontext-current-request-files

Answer (score 2):

What i found out now is that `HttpContext.Current` is an old implementation which should not be used anymore. Because you can not take control over it's content to unit-test it.

`HttpControllerContext` is just the newer implementation. And it's content is also exchangable. The submitted controllerContext to the method initialize is available in `ControllerContext`-Property. So you should use this.

Found this here in first answer:
[Testing a Web API method that uses HttpContext.Current.Request.Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189028/testing-a-web-api-method-that-uses-httpcontext-current-request-files)
Thanks to: Martin Liversage