# mocking httpContext.Current Api controller unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to mock `httpContext` using `Moq framework` to esnure that `httContext.Current is not null` when request comes from Unit test but couldn't really make it working.

After doing google, i came with following steps so for and not sure what steps are next before i make post call to `Api controller`.

step 1

```
Add Moq package to project
```

step 2

```
using Moq;
```

step 3

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

request.Setup(r => r.UrlReferrer).Returns(new Uri("http://tempuri.org/?ReturnUrl=%2f"));
response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
```

Can someone help me out for the next steps i need to do before making Post controller request.

Comment: You should refactor your code to decouple it from `HttpContext` to make it more testable. Having to mock things you have no control over  usually creates more problems than it solves. The level of difficulty encountered trying to create a unit test is a direct indication of how well or how bad your code is constructed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing a Web API method that uses HttpContext.Current.Request.Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189028/testing-a-web-api-method-that-uses-httpcontext-current-request-files)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `HttpContext.Current`, because it does not support unit testing. Inside your `Controller` there are `Request` and `Response` properties which can be used to access any info about Request or Response. Use them instead of `HttpContex.Current`.

Inside you unit tests you can set your own `ControllerContext`. Please, look at another stackoverflow question which describes how to fake `ControllerContext` in Web Api:

[Testing a Web API method that uses HttpContext.Current.Request.Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189028/testing-a-web-api-method-that-uses-httpcontext-current-request-files)

Comment: How HttpContext.Current does not support unit testing? 2) how how i use HttpContext, Request, and Reponse instead of HttpContex.Current?

Comment: Also, i probably can't do new ControllerContext becuase i have web api controller not MVC ..

Comment: OK, thats right. In WebApi you can't have access to HttpContext, but everything you need to know about Request or Response can be received from `Request` and `Response` properties of controller. And you still can set your own `ControllerContext` to controller, but in WebApi it can't have `HttpContextBase` in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it might be a lot easier to write integration tests.

```
    [Test]
    public async Task get_should_succeed()
    {
        //arrange
        var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseUrl, "controller");

        using(var httpServer = CreateHttpServer())
        using (var client = CreateHttpInvoker(httpServer))
        {
            using (var request = CreateHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            //act
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None))
            {
                //assert
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

A simplified version of ControllerTestBase:

```
public abstract class ControllerTestBase
{
    protected ControllerTestBase()
    {
        BaseUrl = "http://localhost/api/";
    }

    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

    public static HttpServer CreateHttpServer()
    {
        var httpConfiguration = WebApiConfig.Register();
        return new HttpServer(httpConfiguration);
    }

    public static HttpMessageInvoker CreateHttpInvoker(HttpServer httpServer)
    {
        return new HttpMessageInvoker(httpServer);
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url)
    {
        return new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not understand a single line what you are trying to say

Comment: Sorry if it is clear enough. Basically by using this code you can spin up a small web service in memory thereby you can define your input then assert the output. Shameless recommend you check this one: http://stephenzeng.com/Home/View/17

Comment: So you mean to say that writing integration test (as explained in the link you shared) will avoid the need the need of faking httpContext? correct?

Comment: That's right. This way you won't need to mock it, while the testing environment is still isolated and can be auto executed in your CI process.