# HttpRequestMessage Content Disposition null when unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to write tests for a custom `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` - one that is very similar to this [MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider.cs](https://github.com/QualiSystems/ShellRepo/blob/master/ShellRepo/Engine/MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider.cs)

In particular, I am trying to test my own implementation of the `GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)` method.

It requires an HttpContent and HttpContentHeaders.

To achieve this I am trying to create a controller context and controller, then pass through the appropriate properties from that controllers request.

In fact, I have tried to implement the answer on this (duplicate) question: [Testing a Web API method that uses HttpContext.Current.Request.Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194413/1678148)

Everything I try results in the `Content-Disposition` on the headers being `null` As shown in the images below:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what I am missing?

For code-sake, here is a copy of the code. You will notice it's the same as that in the answer on the other question. I just can't get passed the null content-disposition.

```
  var content = new ByteArrayContent(new Byte[100]);
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
        var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
        {
            Request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Content = new MultipartContent { content }
            }
        };
        var controller = new MockController();
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

MockController is simply:

```
public class MockController : ApiController { }
```

Comment: Why do you expect `Content-Disposition` to be available on `MultipartContent` while you set it on `ByteArrayContent`?

Comment: Clearly because I'm stupid lol - I felt I had tried that which is what led me to finding that other answer said to place it on the`ByteArrayContent` - not sure how I had it wrong in the first place, though now it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad it helped :). I think I will create an answer if you started a bonus anyway.

Comment: Sure, go for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect `Content-Disposition` header to appear in `MultipartContent` you should set in on `MultipartContent` not on `ByteArrayContent`.

But if you want to emulate file upload form a web page you do need to set `Content-Disposition` header on `ByteArrayContent`. In that case to see the value of `Content-Disposition` you need to iterate through inner contents of `MultipartContent`:

```
var multipart = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
foreach (var content in result.Contents)
{
     var contentDisposition = content.Headers.ContentDisposition;
}
```

You can check this tutorial: [Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2). It might be a bit outdated but it shows the idea.

**EDIT:** Just checked and it appears to be same tutorial mentioned in the answer you referenced in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Here's my analysis of the situation:

The class `MultipartContent` basically has a collection of child `HttpContent` objects (`ByteArrayContent` is inheriting from `HttpContent`). It overrides the `WriteNextContentHeadersAsync` method and writes out the headers from its child `HttpContent` collection. It does have its own `Headers` property, but it is inherited from `HttpContent`, no overrides, nothing special.

So, what you are trying to do, is basically not implemented in that way. The `MultipartContent` does write out the headers to the output, but does not reflect these headers in its own `Headers` collection.

You could override this behavior. Simple and naive implementation could be the following:

```
public class MyMultipartContent : MultipartContent
{
    public override void Add(HttpContent content)
    {
        base.Add(content);
        foreach (var header in content.Headers.ToList())
        {
            if (!this.Headers.Contains(header.Key))
                this.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

So every header from a child `HttpContent` will be added to the `MultipartContent's` `Header` collection. Maybe this is completely wrong and will cause errors and other problems :)

Another option would be to enumerate child `HttpContent` objects in the `MultipartContent`:

```
foreach (var httpContent in (MultipartContent) controller.Request.Content)
{
    var header = httpContent.Headers.ContentDisposition; // here it is
}
```

Another option is to use an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static ContentDispositionHeaderValue MyGetContentDisposition(this HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        if (httpContent is MultipartContent)
            return ((MultipartContent) httpContent).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)?.Headers.ContentDisposition;
        return httpContent.Headers.ContentDisposition;
    }
}
```

If the `httpContent` is `MultipartContent` then return the first not null `ContentDisposition` header from it's child `HttpContent` collection.

```
var hereItIs = controller.Request.Content.MyGetContentDisposition();
```